# Git alias's with arguments that have spaces

Tags: git, shell, alias

I can't find any examples of git alias's that allow arguments with spaces, here is what I have created:

```
cax = "!f() { msg=${1-Default message}; git add --all && git commit -am "$msg"; }; f"
```

This works fine with:

```
git cax "one-word"
```

But breaks with:

```
git cax "one word"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with single quotes? `cax = '!f() { msg=${1-Default message}; git add --all && git commit -am "$msg"; }; f'`

Comment: @VonC That would make sense, but testing on my system shows that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice the odd syntax highlighting in your question?

```
cax = "!f() { msg=${1-Default message}; git add --all && git commit -am "$msg"; }; f"
^^^^^^                                                                   ^^^^         black
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^ red
```

That should have been a big hint. The problem is that `$msg` isn't quoted in your function definition. `"` characters are treated specially by Git when it is reading your config file, but you want to pass these two characters to the shell. Use `\"$msg\"` instead.